# Start with MySQL and change to MongoDB in the future?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, database

I'm new to node.js
I have plan to use database other than MySQL (lets say MongoDB), but I'm only familiar with MySQL.

Do you think better to use MySQL first and change to MongoDB in the future? or learn MongoDB quickly and use MongoDB from beginning?

Comment: Unless you have a reason to use a NoSQL database, you should stick with a normal SQL database.

Comment: this question is not opinion based! It is a fact and a must, that you first explore and get at least basic understanding of database solutions (particularity SQL vr NoSQL) to be able to make an informed decision about the technology you need. Due to the design differences and approach to using those it will be extremely hard to migrate a project from one to another when you already built it up.

Comment: @MarcB I cannot stay with MySQL forever. I want something different. The reason is for learning purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to appropriately use MySQL, then use it.

If you want to learn about MongoDB (or any other thing), then find some time to play with it on toy systems, just as you did when learning MySQL (or any other thing).

If, *after* having reasonable experience with both things, you think MongoDB has a place in your system, then use it. Either replacing or complementing whatever you already have.

But don't do it just because it's the cool thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to wonder why you want to use a NoSQL database. Is it because it's easier to develop for your application ? More efficient ? Scales better ? because of the hype ?

Then, if you think MongoDB is a good choice, go ahead with it. Implementing a first solution in SQL, then switching, looks like a waste of time to me (you will have to change a lot of your design).

Comment: I'm using for fun and learning purposes